# Boto3: AuthFailure when trying to query AWS with EC2 Client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I've created a small python script that is just querying the AWS spot pricing for certain instances, this was working yesterday and has been for the past week. However despite using different credentials the machine I'm running this against is receiving the following error:

```
aws_query = client.describe_spot_price_history(
        StartTime=today,
        EndTime=today,
        InstanceTypes=[
            'g2.2xlarge'
        ],
        ProductDescriptions=[
            'Linux/UNIX',
        ],
        MaxResults=3
    )
```

This returns the following:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeSpotPriceHistory operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

I understand the error, but it makes no sense. The IAM role associated with the instance this is running from definitely has permissions to do this.

There have been no changes that I can think of that would impact this.

Note, this script runs from my local machine fine.

Does anyone have any ideas what may have caused this?

As an alternative - Does anyone know how I can ask Boto3 to confirm the credentials it is using?

Comment: How about test the roles in policy simulator ? https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: @mootmoot I'll add my own answer. The problem actually ended up being a time sync issue on the server.

Comment: Can you raise the issue to AWS forum? Though this is rare, but I didn't find STS mentioned about time zone requirement. So this is helpful if AWS update their documentation.

Comment: Absolutely can! Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I have the same issue, I using TeamCity runner, to run scripts... I changed the local time on my machine where agent is, it's the same with my aws... but I still getting this error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

After a couple of days of banging my head against the wall, I discovered that the problem was in fact with the timezone on the server.

A manual update had been made to accommodate BST but only to the time, not the timezone.

This meant the server was out of sync with AWS and whilst the error was very unhelpful, it was completely justified.

Updating the NTP server and changing the timezone to BST resolved the issue.

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar issue. Is the issue resolved in the subsequent version of boto3?

Answer (score 2):

First check the instance has an IAM role associated with it:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info
```

If you want to get the temporary credentials for the instance, try this:

```
import boto3
print boto3.Session().get_credentials().access_key
print boto3.Session().get_credentials().secret_key
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely has an IAM role and the credentials. Problem persists, but this was actually really useful information to have anyway.