# DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, rundeck

I am running a rundeck job in python in a workflow to start an instance. I receive the following boto3 exception for `ap-south-1` region

```
Regions are: ['ap-south-1']
10:13:58    Traceback (most recent call last):
10:13:58      File "/var/lib/rundeck/pyscripts/rundeck_refactored_code/aws_zabbix/workflow_start.py", line 115, in <module>
10:13:58        start_instance()
10:13:58      File "/var/lib/rundeck/pyscripts/rundeck_refactored_code/aws_zabbix/workflow_start.py", line 80, in start_instance
10:13:58        res_inst = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address', 'Values': [sys.argv[2]]}])
10:13:58      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
10:13:58        return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
10:13:58      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
10:13:58        raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
10:13:58    botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
10:13:58    Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Result code was 1
```

I am using a secret key engine to authorize the access key & secret key from AWS & have defined the policy document defined

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
        ...
```

With python 3.6.8 on Centos7.
boto3==1.14.20

As per the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267553/aws-was-not-able-to-validate-the-provided-access-credentials-authfailed-only-at).

After some time I tried the same script from the virtual machine host instead of rundeck the script executed successfully without any errors.
Request an AWS expert or someone who experienced this to look into this issue.

the code around the error is:

```
    for region in regions:
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
        res_inst = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address', 'Values': [sys.argv[2]]}])
```

I have the access key & secret key retrieved from the secret engine

Comment: Hi! Maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43675610/10426011

Comment: Can you share further your code around `ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')` or something similar? this affects on how you authorize with AWS

Comment: @Leondkr I added the supporting code that you asked

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm your `rundeck` machine date time if it is synchronized or not?

To check your current time on CentOS.

```
date
```

You can consider to use `ntpd` to sync your machine with latest date time.

```
ntpd -g -q
```

Comment: is it possible to reproduce the same error by unsyncing the time? this error happens invariably on some of the servers, whereas when I run with other machines it works well

Comment: I checked the time & timezone. It is synchronised as all other jobs executes successfully